CanOpenNode with stm32
I'm working on CanOpen. I found and used the CanOpenNode open source software. However, the code seems to be running in slave mode. I couldn't switch it to master mode. When it works in this way, I see the message cob id=700+node id on the oscilloscope. Heartbeat is sending the message. It is constantly sending. I want it to run in master mode and send pdo messages. Has anyone made and used it before? I am working with Stm32h7 series processor. I left the github link of the project below. I would be glad if you could help. Thanks in advance.
text
I plan to be able to send the pdo message and see it on the oscilloscope. I have fd can supported hardware.

What do you mean "run in master mode and send pdo messages"? Master mode has nothing to do with PDOs, it is solely concerning NMT protocols. Heartbeat producer/consumer, start remote node etc etc.

@Lundin
I mean I will have one master device to manage the network (STM32H735G-DK)
I will also have a slave device that will send me sensor data with a pdo message.(STM32H562VIT) I want to create a network that is spoken in this way

Again, master/slave has nothing to do with PDO. Apart from NMT, CANopen is not a master/slave topology network. It is just a matter of configuring PDOs.

@Lundin
Well then, if you examine the repository in the link I posted, where can I configure the PDO configuration? Using the code in the example, I changed the pdo cob id to 20+node id. Likewise, I changed the tpdo cob id to 200 + node id. I wrote the sample values ​​I wanted into the communication parameter values. However, I still could not transmit. Where can I do it? What am I wrong?

If you follow a certain "Device Profile" like CiA 401 Generic I/O module, then all PDOs will have to have a default configuration. In which case it has to be configured through the bus with SDO access of the OD, to change communication settings of RPDO and TPDO. If you don't care about Device Profiles or CANopen compliance, I guess you could just hard code the communication settings.

For example it is very common to configure a TPDO to get sent cyclically every x ms regardless of if there's new data or not. In which case you have to modify OD 180n:5 event time, 180n:2 transmission type and maybe 180n:3 inhibit time.

You have to distinguish between the CAN 2.0 layer and the CanOpen protocol stack. The CAN 2.0 communication layer has a multi master topology. CanOpen is based on CAN 2.0, but has a strict master-slave protocol where only one master can be in the network.
If you only want to exchange PDOs, you don't actually need a CanOpen protocol stack, you need the Cob-Ids of the supported PDOS and the format of the 8 data bytes. With these information you can exchange the appropriate CAN 2.0 messages
However, if you want to configure a CanOpen device (slave), you need a CanOpen master. A Can-Slave software package cannot be easily converted into a CanOpen Master. It has a completely different mirror-image structure.

Actually, my goal is
https://github.com/CANopenNode/CanOpenSTM32
To be able to use the software in the library in the link as a master and manage the network. I could not understand how to do this. I can send and receive data packets. But there will be other devices on the network I will connect to and I will need to manage them all. so this library will be more useful. I'm trying to figure it out but I can't figure it out
